# How to keep a react native app running in the background

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

so i am using RN sms listener to listen for incoming sms and i wrote a small code that allows me to anwser the sms if it contains some keywords, in foreground the app works fine however when i close it, it stops
i have used react native background job ,background timer and more but they didnt get the job done
soo all im asking for is a way to run the app once to listen for incoming message and answer them

Comment: HVe you found the answer?

Comment: @Yossi you can use [background-timer](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer) or [background-task](https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task)